# Is there a better way to do this? It seems repetitive

Tags: python

the `if "something" in r or "something else" in r` seems a bit repetitive, is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

```
aiBot = Cleverbot()
r = aiBot.send(question).lower()
ff = ""
if "yes" in r or "of course" in r or "absolutely" in r:
    ff = "yes"
elif "no" in r or "i don't think so" in r:
    ff = "no"
```

Comment: what happens if the answer is `"absolutely not!"`?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if this is the best way to do it but at least if your list starts increasing it should work. Then again a bot shouldn't really be made like that.

```py
accept_list = ["yes","of course", "you get my point"]
reject_list = ["no", "i don't think so"]

aiBot = Cleverbot()
r = aiBot.send(question).lower()
ff = ""
if any(ans in r for ans in accept_list):
    ff = "yes"
elif any(ans in r for ans in reject_list):
    ff = "no"
```

Suddenly thought about another way though probably still not the best

```py
using_dict = {
  "yes":"yes",
  "of course": "yes",
  "no":"no",
  "i don't think so": "no"
}

r = "nope"
try:
  ff = using_dict[r]
except:
  ff="default value"
```